# How can i access the server file system from angular app

Tags: angular, iis

I need to access the file system of an IIS server to create folder inside the hard disk from an angular app. This app i made it myself to create aplications inside the IIS and publish them, but i cant access the file system from the web.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Merv.

Comment: You can't. You would have to create a backend on that server that's responsible for doing so.